# High TTFB with gam identity provider

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I have a project that acts as an Identity Provider (IP) to other "child" projects, I set everything up using gam and ssologin. All of these are created with Genexus, c#
The system should work with a click on a page of the IP which leads me to a certain page of the "child" project.

The link works, but the transition is particularly slow. Also I don't understand if the double pass for the ssologin page is necessary or I am doing something wrong. If I check the elapsed time details most of it is for TTFB

[image]

This I have also shown is the best case. If, on the other hand, the system has not been used for a few hours, times get worse. It is as if the Identity Provider went into standby and put us to wake up, as shown below

[image]

Even the gamssologin code hasn't changed much compared to the standard one, the only difference is the addition of the AuthenticationTypeName to select the right type of authentication (since the projects connected to the IP are numerous)

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this an inevitable behavior of the gam? Is it normal for gamssologin to be called twice?